# ausleihen /leihen auf Deutsch - sind die Sätze richtig?

Tags: meaning

kann ich sagen (1) " Kann ich dein Buch ausleihen?" Can i borrow your book?
oder besser ohne "aus"?
(2)"Kann ich mir ein Buch von dir ausleihen?" ist üblicher?

Im Sinne von "lend":
(3) Kannst du mir dein Buch leihen oder ausleihen?

vielen Dank!

Answer (score 1):

> Kann ich dein Buch ausleihen?

Das ist schon ganz gut, aber denjenigen, der von der Aktion profitiert, solltest du auf jeden Fall nennen. Sonst klingt es so, als würdest du das Buch an jemand anderen weiterverleihen wollen. Also

> Kann ich mir dein Buch ausleihen?

Das klingt sehr natürlich. Der Unterschied zwischen *leihen* und *ausleihen* ist in diesem Fall sehr gering. *Ausleihen* klingt für mich etwas besser.

> Kann ich mir ein Buch von dir ausleihen?

Das bedeutet etwas anderes. Denn jetzt ist es ja nicht mehr ein bestimmtes Buch, sondern irgendein Buch. Der Besitzer wird zwar mit *von dir* weiterhin genannt, es ist aber trotzdem ein nicht näher bestimmtes Buch.

> Kannst du mir dein Buch leihen? (oder ausleihen?)

Auch hier ist der Unterschied in diesem Fall sehr gering.

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst zu den Beispielsätzen: beide sind korrekt.

"leihen" bedeutet das (temporäre) Übertragen von Besitz, legt allerdings die "Richtung nicht fest:

> Ich leihe etwas von dir.
> Ich leihe dir etwas.

In dem einen Fall habe ich etwas temporär bekommen, im anderen Fall etwas temporär hergegeben. "leihen" ist hier in beiden Fällen üblich, sagt aber selbst, ohne die nähere Bestimmung durch Objekte nichts über die Richtung der Transaktion aus:

> Ich leihe Geld.

Da könnte ich sowohl der Kreditnehmer wie auch der -geber sein.

Das "aus-" verstärkt die dem "leihen" fehlende Richtung:

> Ich leihe Geld aus.

Die gegenteilige Richtung der Transaktion wird durch die Vorsilbe "ver-" gekennzeichnet:

> Ich verleihe Geld.

In dem Falle bin ich definitiv Kreditgeber.

"ausleihen" kann zwar grundsätzlich ebenfalls beides bedeuten, weil das "aus-" nicht so ausschließlich festlegt wie das "ver-", aber die Bedeutung "ich gebe Kredit" ist zumindest sehr ungewöhnlich. Die meisten würden hier eher "ich nehme Kredit" verstehen.

Deshalb ist die von @Janka in seiner Antwort ins Spiel gebrachte Bedeutung "ich gebe dein Buch an jemand anderen weiter" für "Ich leihe dein Buch aus." zwar nicht falsch, aber auch nicht das, was die meisten verstehen würden. Sollte die Bedeutung nämlich diese sein, dann wäre "ich *ver*leihe dein Buch" besser verständlich und auch gebräuchlicher.